# How to group data by range

Tags: r

The given dataset contains data such as 1,3,50,76,100,106,209,etc.

I am trying to make a plot so that the data is combined by their range such as 0-99,100,199,200-299,300-399 and so forth.

Comment: See `help(cut)` and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can select data in a certain by putting criteria in brackets as below.

```
x <- c(1,3,50,76,100,106,209)
x1 <- x[x >= 0 & x < 100]
x1
[1]  1  3 50 76
x2 <- x[x >= 100 & x < 200
x2
[1] 100 106
```